# Variables for inputs in modifiers

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to create some terrain in blender, and I have 3 array modifiers to generate the grid. I want to be able to easily change the spacing or quantity of all the arrays with only one adjustment. Currently I have them all linked with drivers to the coordinates of an empty, but I think this is a pretty crude solution. Is there any way I could create a variable that effects all 3 of them at the same time? Preferably it could also feed into my geometry nodes, but that is optional.

[image: my modifiers]

Comment: I would use Geomtry Nodes instead instead of array modifiers. Are you open to such solution? btw i recommend you change the title to something that doesn't sound opinion-based or else your question will be closed